RabbitMQ DeliverCallback is never called after nested RPC
I'm trying to do a simple exercice in Java RabbitMQ, where Entity1 send a message, through Entity2 to Entity3. Entity2 just acts as a middle man, it passes the message from Entity1 to Entity3 and the response from Entity3 to Entity1.
I'm specifically trying to do this with the RPC pattern.
Entity3 does receive the question and sends back the message to Entity2. But the DeliverCallback in Entity2 is never called.
If I exclude Entity1 from the equation and doing 1 RPC at the time, it does work.
The code is basically the same from the RabbitMQ RPC tutorial in Java:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java
Here's the code for Entity1/2/3 :
public class Entity1 {

    private final Connection connection;
    private final Channel channel;
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "QUEUE_ENTITY1";

    public Entity1() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        this.connection = factory.newConnection();
        this.channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        channel.queuePurge(QUEUE_NAME);

        com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback deliverCallback = this::receiveMessage;

        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, (consumerTag -> {}));
    }


    private void receiveMessage(String string, Delivery delivery) throws IOException {
        System.err.println("This callback is useless, won't be executed anyway");

        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }


    public synchronized String askToEntity3() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final String correlationID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        String replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        System.out.println("Entity1 expects the response in channel " + replyQueueName + "\n");

        AMQP.BasicProperties properties = new AMQP.BasicProperties
                .Builder()
                .correlationId(correlationID)
                .replyTo(replyQueueName)
                .build();

        //A variable that will be completed at a later time
        CompletableFuture<String> futureResponse = new CompletableFuture<>();

        String message = "How are you doing ? :D";

        String channelTag = channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(correlationID)) {
                String messageReceived = new String(delivery.getBody());
                futureResponse.complete(messageReceived);

            }else{
                System.err.println("UUID doesn't match");
            }
            },
                consumerTag->{}
        );

        channel.basicPublish("", "QUEUE_ENTITY2", properties, message.getBytes());

        String result = futureResponse.get(); //This is blocking
        channel.basicCancel(channelTag); //Cancel **AFTER** futureResponse.get() (which implies futureResponse.complete())
        return result;
    }

}

public class Entity2 {


    private final Connection connection;
    private final Channel channel;
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "QUEUE_ENTITY2";


    public Entity2() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        this.connection = factory.newConnection();
        this.channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        channel.queuePurge(QUEUE_NAME);

        com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback deliverCallback = this::receiveMessage;

        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, (consumerTag -> {}));
    }


    private synchronized void receiveMessage(String string, Delivery delivery) throws IOException {
        assert(delivery != null);

        AMQP.BasicProperties replyProperties = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId()).build();

        String messageReceived = new String(delivery.getBody());

        System.out.println("Entity2 forwarded to Entity3 : " + messageReceived);

        //Forwards the message to Entity3, get the response
        String responseFromEntity3 = askToEntity3(messageReceived);

        //Give back the response to Entity1, through his queue "amq.gen-........"
        channel.basicPublish("", delivery.getProperties().getReplyTo(), replyProperties, responseFromEntity3.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }


    public synchronized String askToEntity3(String messageToSend) throws IOException {
        final String correlationID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        String replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        System.out.println("Entity2 expects the response in channel " + replyQueueName + "\n");

        AMQP.BasicProperties properties = new AMQP.BasicProperties
                .Builder()
                .correlationId(correlationID)
                .replyTo(replyQueueName)
                .build();

        //A variable that will be completed at a later time
        CompletableFuture<String> futureResponse = new CompletableFuture<>();

        //This is never called...
        String channelTag = channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, (consumerTag, delivery) -> {

                    System.out.println("We got into the DeliverCallback for Entity2!!");
                    if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(correlationID)) {
                        String messageReceived = new String(delivery.getBody());

                        //Completes the variable, if a thread was waiting in .get() it will resume
                        futureResponse.complete(messageReceived);
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("UUID doesn't match");
                    }
                },
                consumerTag->{}
        );


        channel.basicPublish("", "QUEUE_ENTITY3", properties, messageToSend.getBytes());
        String result;

        try{
            result = futureResponse.get();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.err.println("That exception ain't happening anyway");
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        channel.basicCancel(channelTag); //Cancel **AFTER** futureResponse.get() (which implies futureResponse.complete())
        return result;
    }

}

public class Entity3 {


    private final Connection connection;
    private final Channel channel;
    private final Random random;
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "QUEUE_ENTITY3";

    public Entity3() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        this.connection = factory.newConnection();
        this.channel = connection.createChannel();

        this.random = new Random();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        channel.queuePurge(QUEUE_NAME);

        com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback deliverCallback = this::receiveMessage;

        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, (consumerTag -> {}));
    }

    private synchronized void receiveMessage(String string, Delivery delivery) throws IOException {
        assert(delivery != null);

        AMQP.BasicProperties replyProperties = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId()).build();

        String messageReceived = new String(delivery.getBody()); //Actually don't care about the message

        String response  = "No that bug is killing me! :(";
        

        channel.basicPublish("", delivery.getProperties().getReplyTo(), replyProperties, response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        System.out.println("Entity3 sent back his response to " + delivery.getProperties().getReplyTo());
        while(true){}
    }
}

With the main :
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
        Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
        Entity3 entity3 = new Entity3();

        System.out.println("Entity1 asked through Entity2, how Entity3 is doing");
        String response = entity1.askToEntity3();
        System.out.println("Entity1 got the response " + response);
    }
}

I tried with synchronized methods but no luck.
I also tried with active polling instead of the .get() method in CompletableFuture.
I expect the DeliverCallback of Entity2 to be called and deliver the response to Entity1.
Currently, I see that Entity3 does seem to send back the message to Entity2.
But the DeliverCallback in Entity2 is never called.
If I remove Entity1 and send the message with Entity2 to Entity3. I actually get the response.
With that I was wondering if we could do nested RPC in RabbitMQ ?
Thanks in advance for anyone who bothered reading all this.
